# How to use Spark Streaming calculate the mean and variance of streaming data in the past 25 days from Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

There is streaming data in kafka, continuous float number:

2016-11-23 11:00:00|12.2

2016-11-23 11:03:00|13.2

2016-11-23 11:05:00|15.1

......

I want to calculate the mean and variance of these float numbers come between 11:00am and 12:00am in the past 25 days.

Is spark streaming appropriate to handle this problem?

Thanks a lot！

Comment: What does your data looks like exactly ? And how would you know its time is it also present in the data ?

Comment: One more thing , How often do you want to calculate this , mean and Variance , Is this a single time or every second or every day ?

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava I have edited the data format again，pls see the question details。The data format：time|value。

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava I want to calculate the mean and variance every day according to the kafka streaming data。

Comment: Yes you can use Spark Streaming , Steps would be , get data from kafka, filter out the data i.e present between 11:00 to 12:00 from last 25 days , by using SparkSql and then save it as a different topicname in Kafka , so that you do not need to calculate whole value every time and just calculate the new one and then using SparkSqL only apply the mean and Variance methods and get your result. Mean and Variance are present in SparkSql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ming, You can use this as an abstract

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("StreamCount")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
    //update the time according to your need

    // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
    val topicsSet = topics.split(",").toSet
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)
    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
      ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)

    // Get the lines, and timestamp data along with the float values


    SELECT    float_number
FROM      [YourTable]
WHERE     [YourDate] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + '11:00' AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + '12:00'
//store it to a data frame

df.select(avg($"float_number")).show()
```

Comment: The data is continuous come from kafka, so where to store the past 25 days' data? And how to update these data，i.e., the next day how can i remove the earliest day's data and add today's data?

Comment: Could you please agree if the above solution is appropriate to your question.  Please plan to ask another question if you have few more questions on top of that but not a single question for everything.  :)

Comment: Sorry，I'm just a new comer here。I have agreed your answer.

Comment: No worries buddy!! Welcome to Stack !